# Передача структур в функции и возврат структур из функций

Tags: c, ассемблер, структуры

Изучаю то, как структуры передаются в функции и возвращаются из функций. Такой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
        int x;
        int y;
};

struct point makepoint(int x, int y) {
        struct point tmp;
        tmp.x = x;
        tmp.y = y;
        return tmp;
}

int main() {
        struct point pt = makepoint(1, 2);
        struct point *pp = &pt;
        return 0;
}
```

Вот дизассемблерные листинги обеих функций. Попробую их прокомментировать.

Функция `main`:

```
   0x080483e2 <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483e3 <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483e5 <+3>: sub    esp,0x10 ; выделили 16 байт для структуры
   0x080483e8 <+6>: lea    eax,[ebp-0xc]
   0x080483eb <+9>: push   0x2
   0x080483ed <+11>:    push   0x1
   0x080483ef <+13>:    push   eax ; передали адрес структуры скрытым параметром
   0x080483f0 <+14>:    call   0x80483bb <makepoint>
   0x080483f5 <+19>:    add    esp,0x8 ; освобождаем только 8 байт, остальные заняты структурой
   0x080483f8 <+22>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0xc]
   0x080483fb <+25>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   0x080483fe <+28>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048403 <+33>:    leave  
   0x08048404 <+34>:    ret
```

Замечаем, что функция `main` выделяет в стеке 16 байт, но при выравнивании стека освобождаются только 8 байт. Остальные 8 байт заняты структурой.

Функция `makepoint`:

```
   0x080483bb <+0>: push   ebp
   0x080483bc <+1>: mov    ebp,esp
   0x080483be <+3>: sub    esp,0x10
   0x080483c1 <+6>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x080483c4 <+9>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],eax
   0x080483c7 <+12>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10]
   0x080483ca <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   0x080483cd <+18>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x080483d0 <+21>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
   0x080483d3 <+24>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x080483d6 <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx],eax
   0x080483d8 <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx+0x4],edx
   0x080483db <+32>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x080483de <+35>:    leave  
   0x080483df <+36>:    ret    0x4
```

Еще раз посмотрим на это место в `main`:

```
   0x080483eb <+9>: push   0x2
   0x080483ed <+11>:    push   0x1
   0x080483ef <+13>:    push   eax 
   0x080483f0 <+14>:    call   0x80483bb <makepoint>
```

С учетом адреса возврата и сохраненного `ebp`, адрес структуры (push eax) будет отодвинут на 3 дворда, это `0xC` байт, и, видимо, обращение к адресу структуры мы наблюдаем здесь:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
```

А что происходит дальше в `makepoint`? Сложно разобраться в этом коде.

В общем, я так понимаю: когда функция передает структуру другой функции, или когда другая функция возвращает структуру, вызывающая функция сама выделяет место для этой структуры. Потом передает только адрес этой структуры скрытым параметром.

Еще есть такая штука как выравнивание полей структуры. Можно это понаблюдать в листинге? С чем связано это выравнивание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри функции `makepoint` происходит следующее

Локальная структура `tmp` располагается по адресу `ebp - 0x8`. Соответственно код

```
// Копируем x
0x080483c1 <+6>:     mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
0x080483c4 <+9>:     mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],eax

// Копируем y
0x080483c7 <+12>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10]
0x080483ca <+15>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
```

это ни что иное как заполнение полей локальной структуры из `DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]`  и `DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10]` (параметры `x` и `y` соответственно), т.е. это

```
tmp.x = x;
tmp.y = y;
```

А далее идет просто копирование значения локальной структуры во внешнюю структуру-получатель, адрес которой лежит в `DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]`

```
// Извлекаем адрес получаетеля и кладем в ecx
0x080483cd <+18>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]

// Копируем tmp в получателя
0x080483d0 <+21>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8]
0x080483d3 <+24>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
0x080483d6 <+27>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx],eax
0x080483d8 <+29>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ecx+0x4],edx
```

Далее, согласно calling convention, адрес получателя еще и возвращается в `eax`

```
0x080483db <+32>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
```

---

Ваше предположение по поводу

```
0x080483f5 <+19>:    add    esp,0x8 ; освобождаем только 8 байт, остальные заняты структурой
```

не верно (если я его правильно понял).

На вершину стека перед вызовом `makepoint` были положены значения `x`, `y` и указателя на структуру-приемник результата. Выход из `makepoint` был сделан по `ret 4`. Эта инструкция удалила из стека адрес структуры-получателя, но оставила аргументы `x` и `y` в стеке. Инструкция `add esp,0x8` удаляет из стека эти аргументы `x` и `y`, которые вместе занимают 8 байт.

Comment: По поводу последнего дополнения - интересная получилась смесь cdecl и stdcall.

Comment: "Ваше предположение по поводу не верно" Тогда где находится структура-приемник, на которую передается указатель? Я это понимаю так. В функции main выделяется 16 байт для структуры, которая вернется из функции. Число 16 взято из-за выравнивания. Когда структура, выделенная в main, заполнена, лишнее выделенное место (8 байт) освобождается. Остается только 8 байт на 2 поля структуры. Прочитал все полностью, и теперь не понимаю, а где сама структура-то по адресу ebp+0x8. Похоже, надо нарисовать все эти данные в стеке.

Comment: @typemoon: Как где? Структура-приемник сидит по адресу `ebp-0xc` в `main`. В `main` 16 байт выделяется для переменных `pp` и `pt`. Первая сидит по `ebp-0x4`, а вторая - по `ebp-0xc`. Всего - 12 байт. 16 взято действительно для выравнивания. "Лишних" байтов тут 4, а не 8, как вы некорректно полагаете. И еще раз, `add esp,0x8` не имеет никакого отношения к этой области памяти. `add esp,0x8` - это компенсация для `push   0x2` и `push   0x1`, который положили в стек 8 байт. Эти 8 байт по-прежнему остались в стеке после вызова `makepoint`. Вот их и чистят.

Answer (score 2):

Вы с самого начала не с той стороны начали исследование. В зависимости от пожеланий компилятора, он может сделать с вашей структурой всё, что пожелает. Однако есть так называемые [соглашения о вызовах](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5), которые устанавливают ряд правил на то, как передавать параметры. Я бы на Вашем месте начал с изучение этого вопроса. Лучше сразу искать материал на английском (там это называется Calling convention). Кроме того, Вы наверное дизассемблировали код в режиме отладки, а в режиме полной оптимизации он может оказаться совсем-совсем другим. Притом даже вопрос выравнивания компилятор может решать разными способами, чтобы подсказать ему, существуют специальные директивы. Вопрос по поводу того кто выделяет память и кто её освобождает тоже решается по разному. Например, в соглашении __fastcall освобождает стек именно вызываемая функция.

Короче, я хочу сказать только то, что изучение листинга - это самый плохой из способов понять, что делает компилятор, потому что он может делать всё по-разному в разных условиях. Нужно читать документации.

Answer (score 1):

Мое небольшое исследование вопроса.

Добавляю в код вывод, чтобы за счет оптимизаций компилятор не выкинул заполнение структуры вообще:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point {
        int x;
        int y;
};

struct point makepoint(int x, int y) {
        struct point tmp;
        tmp.x = x;
        tmp.y = y;
        return tmp;
}

int main() {
        struct point pt = makepoint(1, 2);
        struct point *pp = &pt;
        printf("%p: %d, %d", pp, pt.x, pt.y);
        return 0;
}
```

Компилирую с оптимизацией `-O1` с помощью gcc (`gcc -O1 -c testmakestruct.c -S -masm=intel`), получаю следующий код:

```
_makepoint:
LFB7:
    .cfi_startproc
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [esp+4]
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [esp+8]
    ret
    .cfi_endproc

; ...

_main:
    ; ...
    ; Заполнение полей структуры (заинлайненная функция makepoint):
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+24], 1
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+28], 2
    ; Добавление значений полей в стек для printf в виде непосредственных операндов
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+12], 2
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+8], 1
    lea eax, [esp+24]
    mov DWORD PTR [esp+4], eax ; Загрузка указателя на структуру в стек
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC0 ; "%p: %d, %d"
    call _printf
    mov eax, 0
```

Часть сгенерированного кода в начале функции `main` для простоты опущена.

При оптимизации `-O2` результат меняется незначительно.

Интересно, что функция `makestruct` в коде присутствует, но из `main` не вызывается.

Ассемблерный код, указанный в вопросе, явно получен компиляцией без оптимизации, иначе компилятор увидел бы, что структура никак не используется, и радостно выкинул бы и её инициализацию, и её саму.

Далее, из-за отключенной оптимизации компилятор генерирует довольно неоптимальный ассемблерный код функции `makestruct`, в котором, в общем-то, не стоит и разбираться (кроме как для спортивного интереса), т.к. в реальных условиях сгенерированный ассемблерный код скорее всего окажется более простым и понятным.

Comment: Как-то все сложно. В том смысле, что если по ассемблерному коду надо восстановить исходный, то трудно догадаться, что здесь используется структура.

Comment: Хотя, наверно, по присутствию lea [esp+24] и загрузки числа по тому же адресу и другого числа по адресу [esp + 24 + 4] можно догадаться об этом.

Comment: @typemoon, вообще, однозначно восстановить исходный код языке высокого уровня по ассемблерному/машинному коду невозможно. Структуры можно определить по косвенным признакам. Да, тут используется указатель, что может говорить, о том, что это структура. Но все равно присутствует неоднозначность: как определить, например, это структура была с двумя однотипными полями или массив из двух элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Формально язык никак не определяет, как именно (в каких машинных командах) компилятор будет выполнять те или иные действия...

Я не удивлюсь, если компилятор вот это

```
struct point pt = makepoint(1, 2);
```

сделает так - сразу начнет писать в то место в памяти, где находится `pt`, не создавая локальной `tmp` - в C++ это стандартная, т.е. оговоренная в стандарте, оптимизация. И, при беглом взгляде на код, создается впечатление, что так он и делает. Впрочем, ассемблер с листа я читаю неважно :(